# Bootstrap dropdown will not respond

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Enclosed is the code for the index.html I am using to build a personal website. I am experimenting with bootstrap and am not well versed in how it works. I have encountered a problem which after much research I have not been able to solve thus my posting it here. I am using a bootstrap navbar with links and dropdowns, the links work, but the dropdowns do not open when they are clicked on, they plain do not respond. what is strange is that they were working, but somehow I have done something and now they don't. Any guidance would be really helpful. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ryan Pace Sloan</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
</script>
<style>
    body{
        background: #0000ff url('blue-texture-circle.jpg') no-repeat top left;

    }
    #name{
        color: whitesmoke;
        font-size: 65px;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
    #starImg{
        color: gold; /*#ccddff;*/
        font-size: 45px;
    }
    #imgDiv{
        border-radius: 100%;
        background-color: lightblue;
        height: 300px;
        width: 350px;
        margin-top: 77px;
        margin-left: 777px;
        border: 2px solid cadetblue;

    }
    #imgDiv img {
        border-radius: 100%;
        height: 280px;
        width: 330px;
        margin: 7px 7px 10px 10px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    #goldA{
        color: gold;
        margin-top: 70px;
        margin-left: 555px;

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong id="starImg">&ast;</strong></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-example-js-navbar-collapse" id="collapseNavBar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="https://github.com/ryanpsloan" target="_blank">>
                    GitHub<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=85723107&trk=spm_pic" target="_blank">>
                    LinkedIn</a></li>
                <li><a href="resume.html">>Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="location.php">>Location</a></li>
                <li><a href="webGL.html" target="_blank">>WebGL &starf;</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a id="portfolio" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Web Dev Portfolio <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="portfolio">
                        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex ="-1"
                                                            href="http://www.easyconversiontools.com">Easy Conversion
                                                                                                        Tools</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem"
                                                            tabindex="-1" href="http://www.unitydictionary.info">Unity
                                                                                    Turkish English Dictionary</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.przm-air.com">PRZM
                            Air</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="contact.php">>Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a id="tweetDrop" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" role="button"
                        aria-expanded="false">Tweets @ryanpacesloan <span class="caret"></span>   </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="tweetDrop">
                        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="twitter-timeline"
                                                            href="https://twitter.com/ryanpacesloan"
                                                            data-widget-id="536299887302701056"></a>
                            <script>
                                !function(d,s,id){
                                    var js,
                                        fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                                        p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
                                    if(!d.getElementById(id))
                                    {
                                        js=d.createElement(s);
                                        js.id=id;
                                        js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                                        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
                                    }
                                }
                                (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
                            </script>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<h1 id="name">Ryan Pace Sloan</h1>
</header>
<div id="centerDiv">
<div id="imgDiv">
    <img src="ryanpace.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<footer>
<div id="goldA">
    &copy; Gold Asterisk 2014
</div>
</footer>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check your JavaScript console's error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be sure to point jquery js file. Because, bootstrap needs jquery. Add this before bootstrap js.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was the solution. Thanks!